# selenium can't test text color

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Hello I am trying to check if the color of an input is red.(Selenium IDE 1.9 Firefox Plugin)

If i select it with

```
<td>verifyAttribute</td>
<td>id=focus_me</td>
<td>*color=red*</td>
```

the "Find" button works, but there is no attribute selected to check.

if i change it to

```
<td>verifyAttribute</td>
<td>id=focus_me@color</td>
<td>*color=red*</td>
```

the element is not found, so how do i use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we are talking about color as a style, your HTML probably looks something like:

```
<span id="custom1" style="color:red;">Custom Attribute 1</span>
```

As you can see 'color' is not an attribute. It is part of the value of the 'style' attribute.

So what you want do is verify that the 'style' attribute contains the 'color:red':

```
<td>verifyAttribute</td>
<td>id=focus_me@style</td>
<td>*color:*red*</td>
```

Note that the asterisk (*) are wildcards. They have been added in case there is another style property before or after the one of interest. One was also added between the color and red since sometimes people puts spaces and sometimes not.

Comment: thanks ! i ended up using <td>verifyAttribute</td>
 <td>id=focus_me@class</td>
 <td>*red*</td>